# Error on Webpage when I approve

Tags: php

I use the Approve button in web page when I click on that it should be approved and the DB should be updated accordingly. But when I click on the button I end up with the below error.

Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19

Comment: Like it says, contact the webmaster. Where are you hitting this approve button? Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Take note of the URL in the web browser address bar when you were on the page with the approve button, then click the approve button. When you see the error page, take note of the URL again. You'll be getting two different URLs.

Tell the webmaster of the site that you clicked on the "approve" button from the first URL and that the second URL does not exist. Mention the URLs to that person as well.

Comment: The URL before approve is http://localhost/www/demosystem/demonew/index.php/SellRecord/2                                  and the URL when I click on approve button is                                                        http://localhost/www/demosystem/demonew/index.php/SellRecord/approve/SG%2F2015%2F03%2F2                                                                             Kindly confirm how I should change the same.                                                    Thanks

Comment: well, if it starts with localhost, then you need to look at the config files. If you're using apache, check .htaccess files for any `RewriteRule` lines as certain requests may be converting to not-found resources via the rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php file defined in form action target,

```
<form action="[your target php file]" method="post">
```

it seems the error comes from it.

Comment: In which file I should find the form?

Comment: Based on your comment in the first answer, the form action target is:

http://localhost/www/demosystem/demonew/index.php/SellRecord/approve/SG%2F2015%2F03%2F2

check on 'approve' method inside index.php file, it seems the error come from it